# disable button click through ZStack

Tags: swiftui

Popup is on  top  of the VStack in the  code below. But the button inside the VStack is still clickable when the Popup is shown (even if the Popup is filling the whole screen and the button below is not even visible.
How can I disable the VStack button when the Popup is visible?

```
//MainView
ZStack {
    if self.showPopup {
        Popup()
       .zIndex(2)
    }

    VStack {
        Spacer()
        Button(action: {
        }) {
            Text("Click")
        }  
        .zIndex(1)
    }
}
 

//Popup
GeometryReader {
    geo in
        
    ZStack {
        Rectangle()
        .fill(Color.red.opacity(1.0))
        .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)
        .allowsHitTesting(false)
        .zIndex(1)
            
        Text("Content")
    }
}
```

Comment: Just not clickable regular button will be confusing for a user, see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of your `.allowsHitTesting (true)` modifier: with this, your view doesn't get touched, and the views below get it.

If you still wanna disable touches for this rectangle for some reason, add `contentShape` to your `ZStack`:

```
GeometryReader {
    geo in
        
    ZStack {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.red.opacity(1))
        .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)
        .allowsHitTesting(false)
        .zIndex(1)
            
        Text("Content")
    }.contentShape(Rectangle())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your click button to disable it when the Popup is shown:

```
.allowsHitTesting(!showPopup)
```

Answer (score 0):

`ZStack` is transparent, you need to disable button explicitly, like

```
VStack {
    Spacer()
    Button(action: {
    }) {
        Text("Click")
    }  
    .disabled(self.showPopup)
    // .zIndex(1)             // not needed !!
```